# Viewable Table [android]

Tags: android

I'm wondering if there is anything that would let me use a table, much like Microsoft excel, for my android app but not editable by users.

I've look at the layouts in eclipse but none of them seem to function well.

Im developing on android 2.2

Comment: [Check this out](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_table-layout/)

Comment: use table layout and add whatever you want add in table row

Answer (score 1):

Try  this coding, for display the table view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Show">
    <TextView android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:textColor="#ff8000"
        android:id="@+id/Entry"  android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="left"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:textColor="#ff8000"
        android:id="@+id/sales"  android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right" />
</TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
```

Comment: In android does not support for user editable. If you wish to apply editable then we can add the listener and change whatever.